# Strange-looking Workbook opened after BeforeClose

Tags: excel, vba

I'm testing some code, which should copy data to a global tracker whenever the user finishes their work and closes it. It's working fine when I test it with a button but when I use it with BeforeClose event the destination Excel opens blank with no ribbon, menu bar, no data is pasted in and there is some strange line visible across the window (see attachment). 
It's random, sometimes it works normally, sometimes it doesn't.
Would anyone know why it's happening?

That's my code:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

 Dim path As String
 Dim wb As Workbook

 Cancel = False
 path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Test.xlsx"

 Range("A1:F10").Copy

 On Error GoTo Handler
 Workbooks.Open (path)
 On Error GoTo 0

 Set wb = Workbooks("Test")
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
'wb.Close False
 MsgBox "OK"

Exit Sub

Handler:
MsgBox "Someone else is saving their data at the moment." & vbNewLine & _
    "Please try in a few seconds"
Cancel = True

End Sub
```

[image: Destination workbook after BeforeClose]

Comment: That line seems to be a shadow.  If you compare with a screenshot of a normal Excel workbook, does that line match where the bottom of the ribbon should be?

Comment: Hard to tell... It seems it's a bit narrower than the ribbon when I compare it. As far as I'm concerned the problem is not only the missing ribbon but also all other missing elements, especially data to be pasted in.

Comment: Consider using an Application event instead of the workbook event. That would enable you to copy the data you want from the closing workbook, let it close and then process the data afterwords. If you are worried about data loss write a log in TXT format with the workbook name and the address of the data, or store the data in CSV format until they are safely put away. As an alternative you could cancel the closing process entirely, process your data and then initiate new Close from the code that did it. I don't think you can do that from the workbook level.

Comment: @Variatus , could you please suggest how to modify the code to do it? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You will find the guidance you need here. http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx Bear in mind that the application's BeforeClose event fires whenever any workbook is closed within the jurisdiction of the class. Therefore you need to make sure the procedures you prescribe don't run on random workbooks other than the intended one(s).